# Resource consumption analysis for different classifiers (Is there any tool ? )

Tags: resources, classification, weka, performance-testing, rapidminer

I'm evaluating different classifiers on a data set. I'll implement the best classifier in terms of accuracy in a smartphone. However, before doing that, I want to compare these classifiers in terms of resource consumption like memory usage, cpu time or battery usage because then I'll be able to compare them in the right sense. The problem is that I'm using WEKA which doesn't have any such resource consumption analysis features. Is there any tool which can give insight into such parameters of performance analysis for different classifiers ? I heard about of RapidMiner but I couldn't find it in their documentation.

regards
Zuhaib

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have submitted a similar article with weka about resource consumption. Weka is a normal java tool therefore it does not supply any tool for your purposes but you can use normal Java and operating system tools.

- [Memory profiling in java](https://www.google.com.tr/search?q=memory%20profiling%20java)
- [Cpu profiling in java](https://www.google.com.tr/search?num=100&safe=off&q=cpu%20profiling%20java)

Both of these google searches gives you [Visual VM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/profiler.html). You can use it to profile your weka program, actually your java code. Also operating system tools gives you another approach like [windows performance monitor](http://www.petri.co.il/performance-monitoring-easy-way-part-1.htm). Similar tools exists for Smart Phones like , [Android profiling](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html), [IOS Instruments](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/InstrumentsUserGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html)

Of course also a lot of different commercial tools exists.

At the bottom line, do not expect any tool like weka or Rapid Miner to bring such tools, even if they do, they would be exception and supported features would be less than any generic tool like visual vm.

Comment: @ Atilla thanks for your comments. I'll explore these options to see if I can get a view on resource consumption in WEKA with it.